# Getting segmentation fault for large values

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

Below program is crashing with segmentation for large n (n > 200), can you please help me out here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    char name[16];
    char num[8];
};
int main() {
    int n, i,j;
    struct node *hash;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    hash = (struct node *) malloc(n * sizeof(struct node));
    for (i=0; i<n ; i++) {
        scanf("%s %s", (hash + (i *sizeof(struct node)))->name,
                        (hash + (i *sizeof(struct node)))->num);
    }   
 for (i=0; i<n ; i++) {
        printf("%s=%s\n",(hash + (i *sizeof(struct node)))->name,
                        (hash + (i *sizeof(struct node)))->num);
  }
 return (0);
}
```

Comment: What strings are you inputting? Any name larger than 15 characters or number longer than 7 digits will cause undefined behavior, which may lead to a seg fault.

Comment: You want to read about [pointer-arithmetic](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/256/operators/2205/pointer-arithmetic#t=201701081538077668512). This `(hash + (i *sizeof(struct node)))...` should be `(hash + i)...` or just `&hash[i]...`.

Comment: Also, your pointer offsetting is hard to read (besides being wrong and reaching beyond the memory you allocated). Let the compiler deal with the size of `struct node` and just write `hash[i]` instead.

Comment: `scanf("%s %s", (hash + (i *sizeof(struct node)))->name,
                        (hash + (i *sizeof(struct node)))->num);` --> `scanf("%15s %7s", hash[i].name, hash[i].num);`

Comment: Also there is no need to cast the result of `malloc()` & friends in C, not is it recommended in any way.

Comment: Do not edit your post to ask another question. It makes the answers bellow irrelevant.. Just use the "Ask a question button".

Answer (score 3):

When you add an integer to a pointer, the compiler performs the pointer arithmetic. So `hash + i` is translated by the compiler into something like `(char*)hash + i * sizeof(struct node)`. The offset **in bytes** is calculated for you, and then applied **in bytes**.

Your code is therefore equivalent to

```
(char*)hash + i * sizeof(struct node) * sizeof(struct node)
```

This will reach beyond the array boundary very fast, invoking undefined behavior.

As the comments summarized, either use `(hash + i)` or the more concise (in my opinion) `hash[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    char name[16];
    char num[8];
};

int main(void) {
    size_t n;
    if (scanf("%zu", &n) != 1) {
      return 1;
    }

    struct node *hash = malloc(n * sizeof *hash);
    if (hash == NULL) {
      return 1;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (scanf("%15s %7s", hash[i].name, hash[i].num) != 2) {
          free(hash);
          return 1;
        }
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%s %s\n", hash[i].name, hash[i].num);
    }

    free(hash);
}
```

Comment: This does in no way explain to OP why his/her program did not work, and therefore does not help OP with understanding and learning how to avoid it further on.